# Converting SVG Path from inkscape to Raphaëljs

Tags: svg, raphael, inkscape

In inkscape the coordinate system is bottom/top corner (meaning, 0,0 is left bottom corner). This is the same case with Adobe Illustrator. But, when I try to use this path string in raphael it use top/bottom (meaning, 0,0 is top/left corner) approach. How to convert this path string according to browser's coordinates or raphael's coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before and the easiest way that I found to solve it is to flip the image before getting the path string.

Comment: If i flip the image, it mirrors the image right? how that'll help to get teh top-bottom coordinates of any objects. Can you explain me more plz.

Comment: Now I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you need. What I got here was that the coords were just like you said.. to solve that, I flipped the image and then got the path string. When I used it on raphael, the image was on the correct orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing a similar issue trying to make a map I created in Inkscape.  All of my countries were off the charts, literally!

I just copied my svg file into [Ready Set Raphael](http://readysetraphael.com/) and it worked like a charm.